# firebase notifications not working in background flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have been facing a problem where I cannot get notifications to be received when in the background. I have a project where the push notifications were working, and so I changed the google-service-info.plist with the new file, and here I was facing the same problem. The notification is not received in the background, but is received after the app is reopened. Does anyone have any ideas as to what might be the problem?
Thanks

CODE USED

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onMessage: $message");
        if(message.containsKey('data')){
          print("Contains Data");
        } else if(message.containsKey('notification')){
          print("Containsn notification");
        }
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onLaunch: $message");
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onResume: $message");
      },
      onBackgroundMessage: myBackgroundMessageHandler,
    );
    _firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
        const IosNotificationSettings(sound: true, badge: true, alert: true, provisional: false));
    _firebaseMessaging.onIosSettingsRegistered
        .listen((IosNotificationSettings settings) {
      print("Settings registered: $settings");
    });
    _firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((String token) {
      assert(token != null);
      setState(() {
        _homeScreenText = "Push Messaging token: $token";
      });
      print(_homeScreenText);
    });
  }



Future<dynamic> myBackgroundMessageHandler(Map<String, dynamic> message){
  print("Background called");
  if(message.containsKey('data')){
    print("There was something in the background");
    final dynamic data = message['data'];
    print("Background data: $data");
  } 
  if(message.containsKey('notification')){
    print("there was something in the backgroudn");
    final dynamic notification = message['notification'];
    print("Background Notification: $notification");
  }
}
```

Comment: share the which you are using

Comment: @SravanKumar I'm not sure what you mean by 'share the which you are using'

Comment: share the code which you are using*
typo

Comment: @SravanKumar Ok thanks, I will put it in the question... (I have tried with and without the background message handler, and it produces the same outcome)